# Doubt on proof of Lebesgue's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am following the proof of Theorem 3.2 on [this](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf) page. Towards the end the author states "By using the Vitali covering theorem and the definitions for $D^+f$ and $D^-f$ it is easy to check the following inequalities $$q|E_q| \leq |f(E_q)|$$ if $D^f(x) > q$ at every $x \in E_q$. But I cannot see why this hold, would anyone be able to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think your goal is to prove the following lemma:**

Let $F:[a,b]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function on bounded interval $[a,b]$. For real numbers $r<R$, define $E=\{x\in(a,b)\,|\,D_-F(x)<r<R<D^+F(x)\}$. Prove that $m^*(E)=0$.

---

**I can give a very detailed (hence long) proof that may be easier for you to understand:**

### Part 1:

Let $m^*(E)=s$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists open set $O\supset E$ s.t. $m(O)<s+\epsilon$. Let $x\in E$. Then $D_-F(x)<r$ implies for all $\delta>0$, there exists $0<h<\delta$ s.t. $\frac{F(x)-F(x-h)}{h}<r$. Collect all of such intervals $[x-h,x]\subset O$, we obtain a Vitali covering of $E$. By Vitali covering theorem, there exists disjoint intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_N$, where $I_k=[x_k-h_k,x_k]$ s.t. $m^*(E\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k)<\epsilon$. Denote $I_k^{o}=(x_k-h_k,x_k)$, then $m^*(E\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k^o)<\epsilon$. Define $A=E\cap(\bigcup_{k=1}^NI_k^{o})$, then $m^*(A)>s-\epsilon$. Moreover, we have
$$\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^N(F(x_k)-F(x_k-h_k))<r\sum_{k=1}^Nh_k<rm(O)<r(s+\epsilon)\tag{1}
\end{equation}$$

### Part 2:

Let $y\in A$. Then $D^+F(y)>R$ implies there exists arbitrarily small $k>0$ s.t. $[y,y+k]\subset I_k$ for some $k$ and $\frac{F(y+k)-F(y)}{k}>R$. The collection of such intervals is a Vitali covering of $A$, so by Vitali covering theorem again, there exists disjoint $J_1,\ldots,J_M$ with $J_j=[y_j,y_j+k_j]$ s.t. $m^*(A\setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^MJ_j)<\epsilon$. It further implies $m^*(A\cap(\bigcup_{j=1}^MJ_j))>s-2\epsilon$. Moreover,
$$\sum_{j=1}^M(F(y_j+k_j)-F(y_j))>R\sum_{j=1}^Mk_j>R(s-2\epsilon)$$
Also, notice that each $J_j$ is contained in some $I_n$, so for each fixed $n$, by increasing property of $F$,
$$\sum_{j:J_j\subset I_n}(F(y_j+k_j)-F(y_j))\leq F(x_n)-F(x_n-h_n)$$
Sum both sides over $n=1,\ldots,N$,
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^N(F(x_n)-F(x_n-h_n))&\geq\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{j:J_j\subset I_n}(F(y_j+k_j)-F(y_j)) \\
  &=\sum_{j=1}^M(F(y_j+k_j)-F(y_j))>R(s-2\epsilon)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

### Part 3:

Combining (1) and (2), we have $r(s+\epsilon)>R(s-2\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Take $\epsilon\to 0$, we obtain $rs\geq Rs$. Since $r<R$, $s=0$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much